# Convert QString or QUrl to Unicode

Tags: qt, unicode, utf-8, qstring, qurl

I want to convert a part of QUrl to Unicode.

I have a given URL, `www.ÄSDF.de` and want to convert it to `www.%C4SDF.de`. How can I do that in Qt?

When I use the method `QUrl::toEncoded()` I always get the converted URL in UTF-8 hex: "www.%C3%83%C2%84SDF.de".

Comment: With -  QUrl::toPercentEncoding(QString::fromUtf8("www.ÄSDF.de")); - i get now the right utf-8 code "www.%C3%84SDF.de", but how can i convert this URL in unicode "www.%C4SDF.de"?

Answer (score 4):

You can't generate `www.%C4SDF.de` with `QUrl::toPercentEncoding` as that function always encodes to UTF-8 byte sequences before %-encoding.

If you really must use a non-UTF-8 encoding like ISO-8859-1 (typically for compatibility with unfortunate legacy applications), you will have to use [`QByteArray::toPercentEncoding`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qbytearray.html#toPercentEncoding) on a byte array you generate from [`QString::toLatin1`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#toLatin1).

However, you probably don't want to do that either. Even the UTF-8-correct `www.%C3%84SDF.de` is not a valid way of specifying the hostname `www.ÄSDF.de` in a URI. Instead it must be encoded using the [IDN algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (using Punycode), giving `www.xn--sdf-pla.de`.

The easy and usually best way to proceed would be [QUrl::toEncoded](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qurl.html#toEncoded). This turns an IRI, eg:

```
http://www.äsdf.de/äsdf?äsdf=äsdf
```

into a working URI:

```
http://www.xn--sdf-pla.de/%C3%A4sdf?%C3%A4sdf
```

(note again IRI requires UTF-8.)

Answer (score 0):

toEncodedUrl has been deprecated in QT5.
I did this:
`url.setUrl(QString(QUrl::toPercentEncoding(s, "/:")));`